# Unable to view user generated logs for azure functions python

Tags: azure-functions

Is it possible to view the user-generated logs for a python azure function if there is no application insights linked to it?

Answer (score 0):

**Update Answer:**

As far as I know it is not necessary, all web apps are deployed on kudu. I usually choose to use kudu to view the logs when I cannot view the logs on the portal due to some problems. What do you mean by kudu not being supported on the consumption plan? Can't enter kudu page? I think maybe you haven't found the right way, you can go directly to this URL (provided that you have logged in to your azure account, otherwise you don't have permission to view): `https://functionappname.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`. Replace functionappname with your function app name, this is the URL of your function app in kudu. You can then view the log in the place written in my answer.

**Original Answer:**

Yes, if you have not configured Application Insights, you can still view the function's health log. The method is to directly enter kudu to view, compared to using Application Insights. Follow this method dont need to delay. The method is below:

[image]

After go to the kudu, click 'Debug console'->'CMD', then go to 'D:\home\LogFiles\Application\Functions>'. Your log file is under this folder.

Comment: Thanks, Bowmanzhu. In order to use Kudu, do I need to have a premium or app service plan? My current plan is a consumption one, and Kudu is not being supported in it.

Comment: @PraneethNooli the comment dont allow me to use too many words. So I will update my answer.

Comment: @PraneethNooli Hi, have you tried it? I have update my answer.

Comment: Thank you @Bowmanzhu for the updated answer. Somehow I'm still not able to open the kudu website for my azure function (I'm getting an HTTP 404 error). I will try to create a new Azure function with a dedicated app service plan rather than the consumption plan and then will try the approach which you have suggested.